# UTM parameters dissappear from URL as soon as the page loads

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, utm

I built the UTM link with Campaign URL builder. But when I try to run that link, the UTM tags disappear and then nothing shows up in Google Analytics. I'm also using Google Tag Manager.

This is the [link](https://www.shridharlifeschool.com/training?utm_source=test2&utm_medium=test3&utm_campaign=counseling&utm_content=test4) I created.

Comment: When I visit that URL it retains the final parameter but not the others. It sounds like your webserver is doing a redirect that isn't preserving the URL parameters. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You are losing UTMs because you have a `301: Permanent redirect to https://www.shridharlifeschool.com/`. Check the server side settings.

Comment: Yes. This was the problem. I had some redirects setup in my old Shopify website... Which were interfering with my new wordpress website

Answer (score 0):

Add a slash to the end of your link:
https://www.shridharlifeschool.com/training/?utm_source=test2&utm_medium=test3&utm_campaign=counseling&utm_content=test4

so instead of doing `training?utm_....`do `training/?utm_...`